# Is there a way to have atom editor automatically open docs related to a particular python module when it is imported?

Tags: python, atom-editor

Basically when I import a module, I want atom to automatically show related object methods and a little information about the method to speed up programming. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is, for example, [autocomplete-python](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-python) which relies on [jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi) to provide *excellent* information for autocompletion.

The gif below is from the package's landing page and shows it in action:

[image: Animation of autocomplete-python in action, from the official repository]